# Send button, which opens UIPickerView to UIPickerView's selectRow function

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have two buttons, which opens one `UIPickerView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var convertFromButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var convertToButton: UIButton!
```

I need picker's `selectRow` function to know, which `button` user press to open it and to change title of this button. So, I need function like this, but I don't know how to send button to this function.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int, button: UIButton) {
    button.setTitle(converter.convertTypes[row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    typePicker.hidden = true;
}
```

Or do I need separate `picker` for each `button`?

Comment: What about saving in some shared memory the latest sender button which was used to open a picker?

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! But I want to understand, if it is possible to send button to function?

Comment: Couldn't you just set up an @IBAction for this?

Comment: @boidkan the OP's problem is when `UIPickerView` already opened, he doesn't know which button was used to fire it. And he is wondering is that possible to set sender button directly into picker. And @Peter, I am not sure about Swift, but in Obj-C Runtime there are Associated Objects. Or you can use `tag`, but there is no property to assign some kind of `sender`

Comment: Thanks, Azat, that's clear it up. `var` with latest sender will be my choice ))

Comment: I added it as an answer because SO rules asks us to avoid answering in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional variable to store the latest sender button which was used to open a picker and check its value in the `pickerView:didSelectRow:`